# Formatting expression misbehaving

Tags: python, sympy

I was playing with Sympy, and I found a strange behaviour

```
In [43]: optimum = Rational(73, 25)
    ...: print(optimum.is_Rational)
    ...: print(optimum, optimum.n())
    ...: print(round(optimum.n(),1))
    ...: print("{:.3f}".format(round(optimum.n(),1)))
    ...: print("%.3f"%round(optimum.n(),1))
True
73/25 2.92000000000000
2.9
2.900
2.898
```

What is happening with the last formatting expression?

---

In response to a comment

```
In [47]: print("%.3f"%round(2.92, 1))
2.900

In [48]: from decimal import Decimal

In [49]: print("%.3f"%round(Decimal('2.92'), 1))
2.900

In [50]: from fractions import Fraction
    ...: print("%.3f"%round(Fraction(292, 100), 1))
2.900
```

---

Python 3.9.14
IPython 8.5.0
Sympy 1.11.1

Comment: round should always return the same type, are you able to reproduce this differently? (like using the value directly, or Decimal, or another way to represent numbers?)

Comment: how about with a sympy.Float object? (as it seems that's what n() returns)